# JavaScript - using apply to invoke function, but 'this' is not being set to the object passed as first argument

Tags: javascript, apply

I'm trying to use the apply method to invoke the `objectify` function, passing an array of values and using `obj` as the object. However, `this` is not being set to the object, but rather the global environment (`window`).

The purpose of this is to get an array of strings, then pass those strings to the function `objectify`. When the function is invoked, it takes the array values, splits them, and, if the object does not have a property with the string value, that property is created.

Here is the code below:

```
let obj = {};
let arr = ["user.name.firstname=John", "user.name.lastname=Smith"];

const objectify = x => {
let cur = this, v;
return x.split('.').forEach(e => /=/g.test(e) ?
(v = e.split('='), cur[v[0]] = v[1]) : cur[e] ?
cur = cur[e] : (cur[e] = {}, cur = cur[e]))};

objectify.apply(obj,arr);
```

The problem is `this` is set as `Window` rather than the object `obj`. How should I rewrite this code so that it sets `obj` as the `this` value?

The end result should be a modified `obj` object so it becomes:

```
obj = {user: {name: {firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Smith'}}};
```

Comment: what a bizarre close reason - using `=>` instead of a normal function is hardly a typographical error - it's not even a syntax "error" (since the code is legal, but doesn't work the way the OP expected it to).

Comment: how is this question off-topic? The appropriate tags were used, a duplicate question was not available on SO, there are no typographical errors, and the problem can be reproduced.
Also, it helps future readers because the majority of information available online explaining `Function.prototype.apply` generally use rudimentary examples instead of more complex ones.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is more a question of arrow function behaviour than the behaviour of `Function.prototype.apply` per se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (no pun intended) is happening because `objectify` is an "arrow function" that always uses the `this` that it inherits from the lexical scope, and will ignore any passed via `.apply` or `.call`.

If you rewrite it as a normal function it should work as desired.

Comment: That did the trick, but now I'm running into another issue where only the first array value is being passed, and any subsequent values are being ignored.

Comment: @DocGunthrop yeah, you're not iterating over the parameter list which will be passed as individual arguments if you use `.apply(obj, array)`.  Since you're using ES6 you should use a "spread" `...` argument and a `.forEach` over the resulting array

Comment: @DocGunthrop i.e. `function objectify(...x)`